# Confusion with Java's "bin" directory in Windows' Path Variable - How can I fix this?

Tags: java, windows, variables, path

So on my server running Windows Server 2008 x64 R2 I installed the Java JDK 7 Update 5.
I added "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin" to the System "Path" variable.

Now in console, certain Java executables like java.exe work, but others like javac.exe only work whenever I'm actually in that "bin" directory.

Does anyone have a clue what I did wrong and how I can fix this?

EDIT: Whenever I enter 'javac' it returns:

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When I type 'PATH', I get:

```
PATH=C:\PROGRA~2\PARALL~1\Plesk\ADDITI~1\Perl\site\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\PARALL~1\Ples
k\ADDITI~1\Perl\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Mail Servers\Mail Ena
ble\BIN;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\Python\Scripts;C:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\Python\;C:\zpanel\bin\apache\bin;C:\z
panel\bin\mysql\bin;C:\zpanel\bin\php;C:\zpanel\bin\wget;C:\zpanel\bin\bind\bin;
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Wind
owsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn";C:\Progr
am Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Mail
Servers\Mail Enable\BIN64;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86
)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;
```

Comment: Do you see `javac.exe` in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin`, Seems you set the JRE's path, please verify

Comment: @JigarJoshi Yes, this is the JDK's path. JRE is either C:\Program Files\Java\jre7 or C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre

Comment: what do you see when you type dir C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin

Comment: @SubinS I see everything that belongs inside the bin directory of the Java JDK 7, including javac.exe...

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to use javac?  Also, when you type PATH in the console, what is returned?  (Please copy and paste both of these into your question.)

Comment: What happens if you type `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\javac` at the console, while in another directory?

Comment: @HarryJohnston it works. but only if i embrace the path in quotation marks like so: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\javac"

Comment: That's normal.  Paths with spaces should have quote lines around them on the command line, but not in the PATH variable.  Try moving the Java SDK directory to the beginning of the PATH instead of the end.

Comment: @HarryJohnston it still is not working. and i don't understand why, i have the exact same setup on my home win7 x64 machine...

Comment: Double-check that you have the 64-bit version of the JDK installed rather than the 32-bit version.

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes, we do have the 64-bit version. though, my teammate _magically_ fixed it yesterday apparently. as soon as he comes on i will ask him how and post it here. thank you for your help =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create also an environment variable JAVA_HOME with path to java

Comment: @Kierrow - did you set `JAVA_HOME` from within the console?  If not, did you restart the the console after you set the env. variable?

Comment: @Attila I set JAVA_HOME from "Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables...". And yes, I restarted the console after I applied the changes. I'm going to try to do another restart...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

For eg:

My JDK is located in my C:\Program Files\Java

So you must do as following:

`Copy C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin , then goto your "Path" variable and set this...`

`And yes.. open you command prompt and give the following command..`

**gpupdate /force**

Comment: Try typing java -version on your command prompt... does it work ??

Comment: Yes, it shows: 'java version "1.7.0_05" - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05) - Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)'